# Schedule a bq command line in GCP with Cloud Pub/Sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a command line that I execute to select data from view and exporting to a staging table in BigQuery:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --headless=true --project_id="XXXXXXX" --target_dataset=XXXXXX --display_name=XXXXXX --schedule='XXXXXX'  --use_legacy_sql=false --params='{"query":"SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxx","destination_table_name_template":"xxxxxx","write_disposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}' --data_source=scheduled_query --service_account_name="XXXXXXX@XXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Is there any way to set the Cloud Pub/Sub topic using the command line?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Create a topic through line command?

Comment: @rmesteves I am trying to schedule BigQuery (Scheduled queries) using above mentioned command. through the console, we have option to set pub/sub topic I need to do same using bq command line.

Comment: How do you want to use Pub/Sub? As a sink or as a trigger to the command? I'm trying to figure out

Comment: @rmesteves as a trigger command

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, by command line, you can't. It's possible by API call with this kind of payload

```
{
  "notificationPubsubTopic":"projects/PROJECT/topics/TOPIC",
  "scheduleOptions": {
    "disableAutoScheduling":false,
    "startTime":"2020-01-24T10:06:12.344Z"
  }, 
  "displayName":"test",
  "dataSourceId":"scheduled_query",
  "destinationDatasetId":"DATASET",
  "emailPreferences":{"enableFailureEmail":false},
  "params": {
    "query":"SELECT 1",
    "write_disposition":"WRITE_APPEND",
    "destination_table_name_template":"test_schedule"
  },
  "schedule":"every day 10:06"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to use the CLI command because I am going to add this in CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @mayurnimavat - This is the correct answer. The CLI does not support all features. In your case I would create a custom program using Python, PowerShell, etc.

Comment: @mayurnimavat Making a `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" ...` and a `bq mk...` what is the difference in your script? Can you detail this pain points?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a little tricky and not so obvious.
I've found this [discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8811) about it.

It seems that `BigQuery's` `CLI` or `API` doesn't support this kind of notifications when creating the transfer configuration.

As it was said in the discussion:

> This means we can't programmatically create transfers with
>   notifications enabled :(

You an find here the [API's](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig) and [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) documentations regarding transfer service.

I hope it helps you.
If you need any further information or support, don't hesitate about asking me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Pub/Sub notification parameter has been added to the API and to the CLI (my CloudSDK version is 382.0). The parameter is `notification_pubsub_topic`.  In my case I need the email notification which is not added yet to the CLI (but to the API). So I added it manually in `bigquery_client.py` in function `CreateTransferConfig`. For sure not the best way but it works for me.

```
emailOptions = dict()
emailOptions['enable_failure_email'] = True
create_items['email_preferences'] = emailOptions
```