# Is there a way to create a scheduled query with pubsub notification using googleapiclient using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, data-transfer

I want to create dynamic scheduled queries using Python and I want to publish a message on PubSub when the query completes. I know I can do that from the UI but that's not what I'm looking for.

Currently I'm doing this, but the "notificationPubsubTopic" field gets ignored in the request

```py
import googleapiclient.http
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors
resource = discovery.build("bigquerydatatransfer", "v1")
body = {
    "notificationPubsubTopic": "projects/{my_project}/topics/{my_topic}",
    "scheduleOptions": {
        "disableAutoScheduling": False
    },
    "disabled": False,
    "displayName": "my_table_name",
    "dataSourceId": "scheduled_query",
    "destinationDatasetId": "test",
    "emailPreferences": {
        "enableFailureEmail": False
    },
    "params": {
        "query": "select 1",
        "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        "destination_table_name_template": "table_name_test"
    },
    "schedule": "every day 09:35"
}
creation_job = res.projects().transferConfigs().create(parent=project, body=body)
creation_job.execute()
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892225/schedule-a-bq-command-line-in-gcp-with-cloud-pub-sub-topic/59895471#59895471

Comment: @Zydnar what does crontab have to do with my problem? I was looking for a solution related to PubSub not to scheduler's per se

Comment: @EnnioNasca sorry not this question.

Comment: I am investigating your case, I found this tutorial which relates BigQuery with PubSub and Cloud Function, it might be interesting to start with: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google released a few days ago the new version of the `datatransfer` [library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/releases/tag/v1.0.0) adding the support for `notification_pubsub_topic` when creating transfer configs.

Comment: I've edited your answer, so that it is more an answer to the question, instead of a comment. Suggesting to close the question is strange, you already have given an appropriate answer, imo - you can simply mark this answer as the solution instead of closing the question. Maybe others have the same problem with a lower version and can see now that the problem is solved in a future version.